# bash script parameter all file with beginning with a specified string

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make the code find all directories start with same letters, this is the code so far. I have two directories `lit` and `lite` I should be able to see both directories with I search for `lit`.

```
for I in $*
do
echo "the directories $(pwd)/"$1" was modified on "$(date -d "$(stat -c '%y' $1)" 
'+%d %d %H:%M'$1)
done
```

Comment: Have a look at [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). You'd need the -type and the -name parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command can take the type of files your looking for, and also perform a search for a given name.

```
 find . -type d -name "lit*" -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Here we set `-type d` for directories and `-name <search>*"` for the name of the files to search for.
You can then execute a command for each result using the `-exec` parameter